# Display Footer Contents Centrally

Tags: css

I am trying to display the contents of my footer centrally, however it does not seem to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```css
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    color:whitesmoke;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    ackground-color:#76323f;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
     Melbourne Public Library Catalogue Site: STAFF ONLY
     <img id ="html" src="Images/HTML5.png" class ="html"/>
     © 2018
</footer>
```

Comment: Just a few small fixes to the HTML section. 1) don't have the spaces between the attributes and the values they equal to i.e. `id="html"` not `id ="html"`. 2) add an `alt` attribute to your `img` tag in case the path specified in the `src` attribute is not a valid image source

Comment: Oh, one more thing to add to the above comment. 3) instead of using the copyright symbol as is, use `&copy;` in place of it.

Comment: please be more specific about 'centrally'. Central to what? Do you want the footer tag centered, or the content inside it?

Comment: Sorry, the contents of the footer.

Comment: @Strato and how is it not working for you? from what I see its working as intended. Are you saying you want it to display like the code? Where the text is above and the image and the image is above the copyright?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you had the word 'background' spelt as 'ackground' by mistake and this prevented the background color to be dark, therefore the white text did not show up and looked like the footer was not displaying. Here is the fixed css block. This should solve the issue, the footer contents are centered. Please let me know if that helped.

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  color:whitesmoke;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  background-color:#76323f;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. Try this:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #76323f;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```